# Tool / command to query debian repository (like repoquery for rpm repository)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, rpm, package-managers

Im basically trying to query the latest version of a package given a repository url & package name.
So if http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ is repository & gcc is package name then is there a command / tool which will help me find the latest version of it available?
i tried using apt-get & apt-cache
the problem is i do not want to add the repository url into /etc/apt/sources.list of the box since i dont have root access.
i tried running

```
apt-get update -o RootDir=<local-dir>
```

thinking i could then add the repository url into < local-dir >/etc/apt/sources.list & run

```
apt-cache show <pkg-name> -o RootDir=<local-dir>
```

but the apt-get update with a switched root-dir fails saying

```
chrooting into <local-dir>/
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

Is this possible? or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an "official" way, but it's easy to write your own script that parses the package list:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
        package="$1"
else
        package="gcc"
fi

release=$(lsb_release -c|awk '{ print $2 }')
file=$(tempfile)

wget -o /dev/null -O $file http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/$release/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz

gunzip -qc $file | grep -A 10 "^Package: $package$" | awk '/Version/ { print $2 }'
rm $file
```

This works if you are running on Ubuntu and are looking for the packages matching your current version. If you're running on another distro, set

```
release="saucy"
```

for example.

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks for that info. I was planning to write a custom tool if none existed. this would certainly help then.

Comment: Based on your suggestion i implemented a repoquery kind of tool for debian repositories. https://github.com/srinivasupadhya/deb-repo-query. far from perfect but i intend to work on it to take it there :)